# CASE zip LIKE MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am creating a "simple" search query. I'd like to select a column that should have the value 1 if a specified column LIKE('test'), it's kind of hard to explain.

What i want to do is like this

```
SELECT *,(CASE mycol LIKE('%test%') as match THEN 1 END) FROM mytable
```

So if mycol matches the condition, then match=1, if else 0. How would i do that? Sorry if hard to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nearly there, but you have made four errors and used one bad practice:

- Add `ELSE 0` in your CASE expression.
- `CASE` expressions need one or more `WHEN` expressions.
- Put the alias in the correct place - after the end of the expression.
- Don't use the [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html) `match` as an alias.

Also, don't use `SELECT *`.

Try this:

```
SELECT
    col1,
    col2,
    ...,
    coln,
    CASE WHEN mycol LIKE '%test%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS zipmatches
FROM mytable
```

However there's no need for the CASE expression in MySQL because TRUE and 1 are equivalent:

```
SELECT
    col1,
    col2,
    ...,
    coln,
    mycol LIKE '%test%' AS zipmatches
FROM mytable
```

Comment: It doesn't work :(
See query:
SELECT zip LIKE '%falun%' as match FROM customers
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Comment: @AntonGildebrand: `match` must be surrounded by backticks to use it as an alias because it is a reserved word. See this fiddle showing it working: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/174f2/2

Comment: It works when i remove "as match". Otherwise it just throws a general error

Comment: @AntonGildebrand: Try using `AS mymatch` or `AS is_a_match`.

Comment: @Mark: there is a minor difference between your 2 versions. For rows that `mycol` is `NULL`, the first version will give `0` and the second will give `NULL`.

Comment: @ypercube: Good spot. I think you are correct. This can be solved using [`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) rather than a more verbose case expression, though it would of course be unnecessary to do this if the column were marked NOT NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another expression

```
SELECT *, IF(mycol LIKE('%test%'),1,0) is_a_match FROM mytable;
```